# Location of Protractor/Mocha test results from last test run

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, chai

I'm new to using Protractor and I encountered an issue where I lost the test results from a test run.  I was wondering if there is some sort of flat file that contains the test run details (test name, pass/fail, etc...) from the last test run so I can parse the results if needed?

The test framework that I'm using is **mocha** and **chai** for the 'expects'

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to specify a json version of your results in your protractor config file. This is mocha/jasmine/cucumber agnostic as far as I know.

> resultJsonOutputFile: 'path-and-name-you-desire.json'

Which gives you an output like this:

`[
  {
    "description": "Login Forms - Username Field Autofocuses",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 30
  },
  {
    "description": "Login Forms - Required Field Message - Username",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 2
  }
]`

Protractor Config Reference:

> https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

Comment: Looks like the json file is also generate after the test run fully completes